# Вставить некий тег "внутрь" хелпера @ajax.actionlink()

Tags: c#, html, ajax, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Можно ли использовать некий тег внутри `@ajax.actionlink()`?
Наткнулся на пример меню
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/7N2le
там элементы меню выглядят как

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center">                                
    <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></h4><br />text
</a>
```

Я же решил использовать вместо `<a>` `@Ajax.ActionLink`, т.к. для моих целей это самое то. Но проблема в том, что из-за этого слетает `<h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></h4><br />`. Вот и вопрос, как быть? Что бы и с Ajax остаться и дизайн меню оставить без особых изменений в css.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри какую ссылку генерирует @Ajax.ActionLink и попробуй составь эту ссылку другими средствами Ajax'a Javascript или mvc и вставь в свой "a href="